# How to Configure Local TinyMCE in create-react-app?

Tags: cordova, tinymce, create-react-app, capacitor, tinymce-react

I am working on a React project using create-react-app which will be deployed as an iOS app using Capacitor.js (similar requirements apply to Cordova environments). I have encountered difficulties in setting up TinyMCE locally and am looking for guidance or solutions.

Problem Description:
The main challenge is integrating a local instance of TinyMCE in a create-react-app environment. Despite placing the TinyMCE assets in the public folder and configuring them in TinyMCE, the editors do not initialize – they just display a blank area without any errors in the console.

I am utilizing the tinymce-react wrapper for integrating TinyMCE with React. Here's a brief overview of my current setup:

```
<Editor
  init={{
    base_url: '/tinymce',
    suffix: '.min',
  }}
/>
```

Constraints:
TinyMCE Cloud: Using TinyMCE Cloud is not feasible due to the requirement for HTTP referer headers, which is problematic in a Capacitor.js/Cordova environment.

Questions:
Are there established practices for successfully integrating a local TinyMCE setup within a create-react-app project, especially considering Capacitor.js/Cordova constraints?

Is there a particular configuration or setup aspect I might be overlooking for local TinyMCE integration in this scenario?

If anyone has experience deploying a create-react-app with local TinyMCE in a Capacitor.js or Cordova environment, could you share your insights or code examples?

I would greatly appreciate any help, suggestions, or pointers to relevant documentation. Alternative approaches that align with our project constraints are also welcome.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `tinymceScriptSrc` to specify the path to TinyMCE

```
<Editor
  tinymceScriptSrc='/path/to/tinymce.min.js'
/>
```

See the [tinymce-react documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-ref/#tinymcescriptsrc) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your response! By using tinymceScriptSrc I was able to resolve the issue. I've been stuck on this for a bit so I'm very grateful for your response.